# Broken(?) Python Install Breaking lsb_release on Pop!_OS

Tags: python, pop-os

I've somehow managed to really mess up my Pop!_OS 20.04 (based on Ubuntu) installation with regards to python. I'm not really sure what I did. From some reading online, a lot of the issues appear to stem from the fact that I am unable to run `lsb_release -a`; it outputs:

```
  File "/usr/bin/lsb_release", line 25, in <module>
    import lsb_release
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'lsb_release'
```

There's a solution [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/1003535) on this forum, but I appear to be missing the `site-packages` folders:

```
jhonig@computer:~$ ls /usr/local/lib/python*
/usr/local/lib/python2.7:
dist-packages  site-packages

/usr/local/lib/python3.7:
dist-packages

/usr/local/lib/python3.8:
dist-packages
```

I have also tried installing Python 3.5 and running lsb_release with it, but no dice:

```
jhonig@computer:~$ python3.5 /usr/bin/lsb_release
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/lsb_release", line 25, in <module>
    import lsb_release
ImportError: No module named 'lsb_release'
jhonig@computer:~$
```

### Here's some more information that might be helpful for debugging:

I get a message about this error when I try to install something with pip as well:

```
jhonig@computer:~$ pip3 install flask
Defaulting to user installation because normal site-packages is not writeable
[Further lines redacted for brevity, but Python is complaining that lsb_release returned non-zero exit status 1]
```

[Here](https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/rsZHmrxPms/) is a list of all of my installed Python packages. I'm guessing this issue is due to version conflict, but I have no idea where to start, as I've already bricked my system once by uninstalling python2.7 (yes, I know, it was dumb).

I am also unable to run some applications, like the GNOME Terminal:

```
jhonig@computer:~$ gnome-terminal
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/gnome-terminal", line 9, in <module>
    from gi.repository import GLib, Gio
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'gi'
jhonig@computer:~$
```

A little more information that may be helpful:

```
jhonig@computer:~$ type -a python3
python3 is /usr/bin/python3
python3 is /bin/python3
jhonig@computer:~$ python3 --version
Python 3.7.9
jhonig@computer:~$ type -a python
python is /usr/bin/python
python is /bin/python
jhonig@computer:~$ python --version
Python 2.7.18rc1
jhonig@computer:~$ which python3
/usr/bin/python3
jhonig@computer:~$ which python
/usr/bin/python
jhonig@computer:~$ ls -lah /usr/bin/python3
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 18 Oct  1 14:01 /usr/bin/python3 -> /usr/bin/python3.7
jhonig@computer:~$ ls -lah /usr/bin/python
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 24 Oct  2 10:52 /usr/bin/python -> /etc/alternatives/python
jhonig@computer:~$ ls -lah /etc/alternatives/python 
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 18 Oct  2 10:55 /etc/alternatives/python -> /usr/bin/python2.7
```

I again suspect that this will be fixed when the lsb_release issue is fixed, but I don't know.

Thank you in advance!!!

Comment: I suspect your issue is that you replaced the system default Python with a different version.  What are the outputs from `type -a python` and `python --version`.  What version of Pop!_OS are you using?

Comment: `type -a python` gives `python is /usr/bin/python \n python is /bin/python`; `python --version` gives `Python 2.7.18rc1`.

Comment: You did not mention which version of Pop!_OS you are using, but it seems that versions after 18.04 have both Python 2 and 3 available as system versions.  Looking at `/usr/bin/lsb_release` from 18.04, it wants to use the system default Python 3.  So what are the outputs of `type -a python3` and `python3 --version`?  Please add all that to your question as well as state which version of Pop!_OS you are using.

Comment: I've added this information to my question. Thank you for your assistance. @GracefulRestart